# Burninate [slimframework]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [slimframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slimframework) is a duplicate of [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim), also its only used 10 times. So it should get replaced with [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim) and then removed.

Comment: Sure, why not do it right now? Editing 10 questions into shape while removing this tag should take less than an hour.

Comment: Synonymized with [slim]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag is now burninated. Both tags are clearly duplicates so if it comes back, you may want to suggest a synonym, instead of doing this work all over again.

I edited each question, removing [slimframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slimframework) when [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim) was already present, or replacing [slimframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slimframework) with [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slim). In the process, I improved each question by fixing the formatting, the grammar, rewording the post and the title.